# Bathroom electrical outlet issue

Tags: electrical, gfci

I recently changed a GFCI that was incorrectly installed. After installing the new outlet, nothing on load side is working. On a multimeter only reading @ 89 volts on hot and neutral, but hot to ground getting 120. Also at outlet getting 120 at line/load terminals.

Comment: Bad neutral contact?  Is this outlet on its own circuit or chained off another?

Comment: GCFI outlets don't always have the line and load terminals in the same position. Did you get that right?

Comment: Have you pressed the test and reset? Even properly connected many GFCI’s require the test reset cycle to activate them even when properly connected.

Comment: Thanks I will try all the suggestions. I am leaning toward a break in the neutral chain on the load side.

Answer (score 4):

### When hooking up a new GFCI, only hook up "Line" first

At that point, have a "check point" in your work. Turn the circuit back on, and test that the GFCI is able to test, reset, and power a load.

If it doesn't, stay with *that* problem until you have resolved it.  Don't fool around with hooking up any other wires until you clear that check point.

### Then when that's working, hook up any other wires

Then turn the circuit back off and connect one downline cable at a time.  Happens all the time where stuff breaks *at this point*.  However, you know what works: you know "the supply wires are correct".  Don't change them.  Any problems you're having at this point are with the thing you just added.  Either you connected it wrong, or there's a fault in that leg which the GFCI is detecting, or there's some other problem in that leg.